# How to custom Modal View Controller presenting animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, modalviewcontroller

Instead of setting uiviewcontroller's `modalTransitionStyle`, I want to add an CAAnimation(or some other thing). This code can perform an custom animation in navigationController

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
          transition.duration = 0.4;
          transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
          transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
          [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:adjustViewController animated:NO];
```

How can I implement it to a Modal View Controller?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You just need to add the transition to the window's layer, and present your controller rather than pushing it:

```
     CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
     transition.duration = 1;
     transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
     transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
     [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
     [self presentViewController:adjustViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing this rather than setting up a delegate that implements UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?

Comment: The code above works since iOS2, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning is present since iOS 7.0

Answer (score 8):

**Swift Version**

```
let viewController = YourViewController()
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

From apple develop guide:

[Presenting a View Controller Using Custom Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)

To present a view controller using custom animations, do the following in an action method of your existing view controllers:

- Create the view controller that you want to present.
- Create your custom transitioning delegate object and assign it to the view controller’s transitioningDelegate property. The methods of your transitioning delegate should create and return your custom animator objects when asked.
- Call the presentViewController:animated:completion: method to present the view controller.

...

Comment: You also need to set the view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`.  This method is more correct than using `CATransition` post iOS 7 (2013)