# Show popup everywhere in app like UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, popup, alert

I have a popup class for showing some message across my entire app.
I have to init an instance and add it as a child of a currently appearing controller then show the popup view whenever I want:

```
func popMessage() {
    let popup = MyPopup()
    self.addChildViewController(popup)
    self.view.addSubView(popup.view)
    popup.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    popup.show()
}
```

Sometimes the current view controller is embedded in `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`.
In case of making my popup view show in whole screen size without being clipped by the navigation bar or tab bar, I have to add it as child of the navigation controller or tab bar controller. This is annoying when I decide to change controller hierarchy.

How can I make it easier like using an UIAlertViewController:

```
let popup = MyPopup()
popup.show() 
or 
self.presentViewController(popup)
```

Pop it anywhere and make it the only focus on screen without regarding which parent view controller the popup should have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can present your popup on root view controller of application window.

```
let popUp = MyPopup()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate  as! AppDelegate
let appWindow = appDelegate.window
var topViewController = window?.rootViewController

    while topViewController?.presentedViewController != nil
    {
        topViewController = topViewController?.presentedViewController
    }

topViewController.presentViewController(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That helps! And what if I want to pop it with animation using `UIView.animateWithDuration`rather than presenting it modally? Is adding popup as a child view controller the only way to animate it's own view?

Comment: if you are looking for present view with custom animation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931710/how-to-custom-modal-view-controller-presenting-animation